# Are Java pointer writes atomic?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, atomic

Simple question: does the Java memory/synchronization model guarantee atomic pointer writes?  That is, if we have competing threads:

```
String shared;

thread1()
{
    shared = "a";
}

thread2()
{
    shared = "hello world";
}
```

started at the same time, is `shared` always guaranteed to be `null`, `"a"`, or `"hello world"`?

Comment: Note, in general, the object referenced by the reference may not be fully initialised. The normal implementation of `String` should be okay, although the specification isn't great on these sorts of things. Also there are precious few actually immutable types. If you try relying upon this sort of thing, you are probably doing something wrong (although that isn't a good reason for not understanding why).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reads and writes are atomic for reference variables.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Answer (score 7):

It is atomic.

However, in the example you gave, `shared`'s value isn't necessarly **one** of `null`, `a` or `hello world`. It is possible that, without proper synchronization, each thread will never see the value set by other threads. So `thread 1` will see `a` and `thread 2` will see `hello world` at the same time.

**Edit: Added references for the last paragraph for further reading**

The JLS explains the order of operation performed by different threads, in [Chapter 17 - Threads and Locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html). Specifically, in the [17.4.5 Happens-before Order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5) section. Also, the well-written [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/) explains all of this thoroughly.

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing as "at the same time" in this context. With synchronization, they won't occur at the same time. Without synchronization, there is no well-defined concept of "time" that applies.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz for this matter, the term "time" is used as it is used any place else in our world. It means that at 9:00 AM today, `thread 1` treated `shared` with value `a` and `thread 2` treated it as `hello world`. I don't think it get more simple than that.

Comment: That use of "time" is inapplicable to two non-instantaneous things that don't have well-defined starts or stops and that are not synchronized. For example, if you want to ask if two people were "getting ready for work at the same time", you must have a precise definition of when "getting ready for work" starts -- whether hitting the snooze button on your alarm clock is part of "getting ready for work" or not. If that's not well-defined, the concept of "getting ready for work at the same time" isn't well-defined either. In this context "did they happen at the same time?" has no useful answer.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz You're totally right but that's getting philosphic about something quite clear. This misconception of the term "time", when applied to read/write operations from different threads (run by different CPUs), is exactly the reason for the confusion that comes along with the fact that I have mentioned. It is **essential** to use the term "time" with its wide-use definition (or any dependent term) in order to realize that typically counter-intuitive fact.

Comment: I don't believe it's necessary to say something false or misleading to get someone to understand something. It may take a tiny bit more effort, but ultimately you'll contribute much less to confusion if you say things that are simplified but *true*. There is simply no coherent notion of "at the same time" that applies to these kinds of operations, and it's not helpful to pretend that there is. There is simply no defined ordering between unsynchronized operations.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I disagree. In an answer's scope, I see no reason to further elaborate. IMHO the answer is as clear as needed. If you think it can be done in a more accurate or concise way, you're invited to add an answer. I will add, however, reference for further relevant information.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. From [section 17.7 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7):

> Writes to and reads of references are always atomic, regardless of whether they are implemented as 32-bit or 64-bit values.

(That doesn't mean you'll always see the "latest" value, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: As a corollary, why would Java's specification demand atomic 64-bit pointer writes but not the same for `long` writes?

Comment: @donnyton, references must be atomic and I know no language where references/pointers are not atomic (if properly aligned). As for why longs are not specified to be atomic - that will include 32bit architectures and atomic writes might be more expensive to achieve while references on 32bit systen are just... well 32bit wide.

Answer (score 3):

It will be one of those three values, yes -- but which is undefined.  Last one in "wins".

You didn't ask, but for completeness - it will NOT be "hello wor" or some partial version of that string.